# Performance Hits for Caching Data in Memory

Tags: asp.net, caching

Using the runtime in-memory cache in ASP.NET, what are the potential pitfalls of storing data? How much data is "too much" generally, and on what scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting around to testing some code which intensely uses the cache, there is no appreciable impact on performance that I can measure. It seems that when the cache approached memory limits, it simply kicks the oldest content off early, and so the performance impact is negligible.

Comment: There's more to this.  For example, Web Gardens, web farms, etc require a lot of consideration before using the asp.net in-memory cache and can be huge pitfalls.

Comment: True, with web farms / gardens there will be more RAM used than necessary. One way to accommodate that, however, is to designate a single cache ad use tempting to get to it.

Comment: Then the question becomes one of performance / complexity of implementing the cache vs increasing performance of the primary source (db).  Often databases can be tuned to be far more performant than they typically are, thus invalidating the need for a cache in the first place.  In numerous situations I've seen *network* performance be a bigger limiting factor than the DB server - and if you have to use yet another machine on the network to pull that then you could actually have a large negative impact.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write "use remoting" not "tempting" on my last comment... Silly autocorrect...

Comment: Great point! There is a pitfall there too though... if connecting to a database from the code behind, one needs to keep an eye out for using unmanaged memory resources, which often requires implementing iDisposable or having the using clause.

Comment: Also, I'm curious... The database might be optimized, but how do you get around tea most inevitable delay because of having to connect to it and all that stuff... The patterns I've seen before only connect the the database when necessary or refer to the cache otherwise. As I imagine it, using a db like a cache might slow things down?

Comment: connections in .net are cached, so after the first hit it'll be instant on future queries.  Use `using` and you're fine.  And, yes, copying your data to a DB for caching *could* cause a slow down - heck, copying it to an in-memory cache on a third machine could cause a slow down.  Hence the reason I say that there's far more to this than just the limited test you posted about.

Comment: Now, if you are dealing primarily in STATIC data, then a local asp.net in-memory cache would be fine regardless of how many times that data is copied amongst web gardens / farms.

Comment: Hmm... Very helpful information there. I did not know that the connections are cached. I think a good second question I could take a deep look at is whether a scheme to synchronize an in memory cache using remoting has a better or worse impact as compared to the scenario you just suggested. This is all good discussion. I'm building a CMS that I want to commercialize, so I will have to examine these issues in depth.